# Difference between "select new" and "Select(a => new"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by

please consider this 2 queries and their result:

```
var result = ent.tblCustomGroupBies
            .GroupBy(a => groupA.Contains(a.Group.Value) ? "A" :
                          groupB.Contains(a.Group.Value) ? "B" :
                          "N/a")
            .Select(a => new
            {
                KEY = a.Key,
                VALUE = a.Count()
            });
```

and it's result in `GridView`::

[image]

and the second query:

```
 var result3 = from p in ent.tblCustomGroupBies
               group p by new { Criterion = groupA.Contains(p.Group.Value) ? "A" : 
                                            groupB.Contains(p.Group.Value) ? "B" : 
                                            "N/a" }
               into g
               select new { KEY = g.Key, VALUE = g.Count() };
```

and it's result in `GridView`::

[image]

why `Select(a => new)` in first query show key column but `select new` does not show that?

Comment: Where is the code that produces your output?

Comment: Is the Result wenn you watch the variables in debug mode the same inside both variables ? How do you visualize them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var result3 = from p in ent.tblCustomGroupBies
               group p by new { Criterion = groupA.Contains(p.Group.Value) ? "A" : 
                                            groupB.Contains(p.Group.Value) ? "B" : 
                                            "N/a" }
               into g
               select new { KEY = g.Key.Criterion, VALUE = g.Count() };
```